# How can I see a stock's key events in a Google query?

Tags: stocks

In this screen capture, this person is able to bring up Nvidia's key events when doing a google query for the stock, however, when I do the same I get a lot of information on the stock but one thing I don't get is these key events, what do I do to see these?

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: @keshlam They didn't explicitly point it out, however, it's the exact same window format and info you get over at google.finance except that I get a "compare to" option instead of the key events layout that the person in the screen capture gets. However, I don't mind any particular website, if anyone knows of another website that displays the same the information in a chart like seen in the capture then that works for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows by default under Google Finance. Did you select a time period greater than 6 month?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, turns out this happens because I'm in a different region, changing the region to USA fixes it.